# Custom edit form associated with edit button on list view

Tags: list, custom, form, view

I have created a view from a list which I created.  I now have an edit button link on this view and need to link it to a custom edit form.  How can I do this in SharePoint Designer.  I am using Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript/jQuery you can do the following:

1) Change the href of your Edit Link. Append a custom query string parameter at the end of the link. Example:

```
http://server/Lists/MyList/EditForm.aspx?ID=1&OpenCustomEditForm=1
```

2) In the EditForm.aspx, add a script which checks whether the custom query string parameter is present in the `window.location.href`.

3) If the parameter is present, hide the fields which are not needed in the Custom Edit Form.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("OpenCustomEditForm=1") != -1){
      //Hide unnecessary fields.
}
```